# Visual Studio 2015 / Win10: appcrt140.dll missing

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently converting a solution of command line executables linking against static libs from VS2013 to VS2015. Everything compiles and linkes fine, however, when executing the command line executable the new `appcrt140.dll` is not found:

[image]

I installed both the x86 and x64 VC redistributable. From what I read online, it should be part of Windows10, however, I'm not able to detect this file on my system. Also, the `desktopcrt140.dll` is missing on my system; both of which should be part of the VS2015 redist (see [Visual C++ Runtime Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/2015-redistributables-rc-vs.aspx)), however, they seem not to be installed along with VS2015 Enterprise:

[image]

What am I missing here / how do I install the missing dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the CRT has suffered major changes between VS2015 CTP1 and the current VS2015 (more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx)) one of them being the replacement of both of your missing dlls with what they call a universal CRT (which is as stated a part of Windows 10).

> The AppCRT and DesktopCRT have been recombined into a single library, which we have named the Universal CRT.

Judging from this I would say you should upgrade to newest version of VS2015 if you are not using it already. If you are already using that and getting this error then it could be due to a dependency that was buit with VS2015 CTP1.

Comment: VS2015 was [released](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx) it is no longer a CTP

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm on VS2015 Enterprise 14.0.23107.0. I have both `ucrtbase.dll` and `ucrtbased.dll` installed on my system. Still, I'm wondering why my application is looking for the (seemingly obsolete) `appcrt140.dll`. Now I'm guessing that it's related to some precompiled dependency, that I'm pulling in using NuGet (v140 boost and zlib are likely candidates). Is it possible to determine the dll that requests / falsely links against `appcrt140.dll` using some tool like dependency walker?

Comment: @jmartinez yes, dependency walker will help you with this - it will show if the dlls are linked directly by your module or by a dependency. Btw does an empty console app also suffer from this? If no the issue is most likely caused by a dependency.

Comment: The problem was caused by a faulty dependency ([cpprestsdk-2.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/2.5.0)), since this dll linked againsted `appcrt140.dll`. Updating to [cpprestsdk-2.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/2.6.0) solved the problem, everything is working flaweless now.

Comment: so anyone knows where to download appcrt140d.dll ?