# Missing appcrt140d.dll while trying to run cocos2dx Debug.win32. Where to get the dll?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, msvcrt

I cooperate on a game project in cocos2dx. I do not code, rather work on scenes in Cocos Studio. When I've tried to run .exe build in proj.win32/Debug.win32 it started to throw errors about missing .dll. I've downloaded them as it was requesting them (msvcp140d.dll, vcruntime140d.dll), but I cannot find appcrt140d.dll anywhere.

What would you recommend me to do?

I've tried to install C++ Redistributables without any effect.

Comment: What is the version of Visual studio you have? You might want to refer this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129787/visual-studio-2015-win10-appcrt140-dll-missing

Comment: I do not have it installed - well, that should most likely solve the problem. @Guilt has offered me also a link about Preparing a Test Machine

Comment: There is no point in testing the Debug build of the product.  Contact whomever builds it and ask for the Release build.  And the missing DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d` suffix there means that this is a *debug* version of the DLL. Which makes sense—like you said, it was compiled as a "Debug" build, which is going to use a special debugging version of the C runtime library designed to help you catch errors.

You aren't supposed to release debugging versions of your applications for general use. In fact, Microsoft doesn't even make the debug versions of its runtime DLLs available. They are considered "non-redistributable." That's why you aren't getting them when you download and install the C++ Redistributables. All you get are the release versions of the DLLs.

If you are not a programmer, you will probably not find a debugging build particularly helpful. The error messages won't mean anything to you, and the extra error-checking code will just slow things down. Unless your friend the programmer has specifically *asked* you to help him debug his program, then you should ask him for a release build. That way, all you'll need to install is the appropriate version of the C++ Redistributable (version 14 → VS 2015).

If you want to run the debugging build, you'll need to obtain the non-redistributable debug-only versions of the runtime DLLs from your friend. They are installed with Visual Studio. He should know where to find them. If not, tell him to look in his Visual Studio directory (under the Program Files directory), in `\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\`. Copy the required DLLs to the same directory as the EXE and you'll be in business.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Those are debug versions of the runtime environment. They are normally installed when you install Visual Studio 2015. If you do not want to do that, you can find more instructions on how to proceed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx

Comment: I do not have VS installed, as I understood it my fellow developer should help me with the set up of the test PC. Hope it works, thx for the link.